# Bot Framework Embedded Chat - Can I customize the prompt?

Tags: c#, chat, botframework

I created a prompt message for my bot, so that when a user is added to a conversation it says Hi and what it can do. However, when I published this bot and run it through the embed chat code, there is already a prompt in the chat - Can I remove this Prompt? Or at least edit it?

Example in picture:

[image]

Comment: Bot Framework released a new WebChat control that does not send a canned greeting message. It also has richer support for Markdown, Cards, and Attachments. The control is in still preview, so you must opt into it on the Bot Framework Dev Portal at https://dev.botframework.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently not available but filed as a bug here - subscribe if you'd like to be notified when this is resolved:

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1149

Answer (score 0):

Not at this time.  We know its on the wish list though, so hopefully soon.